# How to connect and communicate with a signalr websocket without installing/using node.js/.net?

Tags: python, websocket, signalr

How to communicate with a signalr websocket without having to use node.js or other non-Python dependencies?

For example, how to connect to the following websocket:
https://github.com/ericsomdahl/python-bittrex/issues/57#issuecomment-343772197

Running the code from the above example results in:

```
OSError: Missing Node.js runtime. Node is required. Please read the cfscrape 
README's Dependencies section: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape#dependencies.
```

Likewise the following sample application from python's `signalr-client` has many non python dependencies:
https://github.com/TargetProcess/signalr-client-py#sample-application

How to connect and communicate with signalr websockets without needing to install any non python dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample application you linked to is a sample signalr server so that the python-client has something to talk to - if you have a signalr service already, you do not need to build or run that (.net) app to use the python signalr-client client in your python programs. See the requirements file: https://github.com/TargetProcess/signalr-client-py/blob/develop/requirements . Python only!